# Line spacing in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Now the lines inside each row too close:

```
 <table class="topics" >
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 0 5px 0 0; color:#3A5572; font-weight: bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="padding: 0 4px 0 0;">1.0</td>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 0 5px 0 0; color:#3A5572; font-weight: bold;">test2</td>
            <td style="padding: 0 4px 0 0;">1.3</td>
            <td>def</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I try change `.topics td { line-height: 16px; }`  but same. I want lines inside row to be further.

Comment: Increase the `line-height` further? Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/m97Sh/

Answer (score 3):

Just increase the line height eg. `.topics td { line-height: 30px; }` . Here you can see your code running: http://jsfiddle.net/XLRwu/

Answer (score 2):

```
 .topics td { line-height: 30px; }
```